# Create a Flutter module for desktop apps

Tags: windows, xcode, flutter, macos, dart

Currently, when running the command `flutter create -t module --org com.example app` we are able to generate a Flutter module which we can add to a host parent app. The command though only supports it for mobile (Android and iOS). I need to do something similar with windows and macos desktop apps since Flutter supports those platforms as well and I have existing desktop apps that I'd like to augment with Flutter UI. Is it currently not possible to do so? Is there a workaround as to how to get a Flutter module to be hosted by a parent desktop app?

For reference, this is the documentation for adding a module  https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app

Answer (score 0):

I can launch a flutter View Contorller by following step. Mabye this way is much like using Flutter module for mobile.

**Step 1.** Create a Flutter desktop project.

**Step 2.** Build your Flutter project. and you can get App.framework and FlutterMacOS.framework.

**Step 3.** Add those frameworks to your project.
[image]

**Step 4.** Add FlutterViewController like Flutter module for mobile.
[image]

**Step 5.** Make sure add sandbox connections privilege. Otherwise dart vm would print an error.
[image]